# iPhone 5 dimensions suddenly supported?

Tags: iphone, ios, screen, iphone-5

I have no idea if it was something I did, or some update.  But I've been programming an app that used the dimensions of pre-iPhone 5 devices, and the other day I noticed that my app started utilizing the entire screen instead of giving me the black bands I was getting before.

I thought it was because I imported a background image with the dimensions of an iPhone 5, and I assumed there was some black magic/dimension recognition going on, but I checked older versions of my code in my git repo and they all see to be utilizing the full screen dimensions as well.

Can anyone help me shed some light on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to define the app "supports" iPhone 5 layout, add a launch image of iPhone 5 dimension , i.e. `Default@2x-568h.png`

Comment: if he can add iPhone 5 launch image & xCode identifies it, his xCode is new enough (i.e. version >= 4.3 )